# Updating Field Mappings Parameter on table selection in Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, tool-validation

I am building a python toolbox with ArcPy and would like to associate an input feature class parameter with a field mapping. I want the input dialog to work as it does in many built-in geoprocessing tools (e.g. Dissolve), so that once user selects the input feature class the field map populates with the input fields.

I have tried:

- `fieldMapParameter.addTable(feature_class_parameter.name)` in the `updateParameters` method but throws error *ParameterObject: Get attribute: addTable does not exist*
- Setting `fieldMapParameter.parameterDependencies = [param1.name]` doesn't seem to have an effect.

  ```
  def getParameterInfo(self):
      """Define parameter definitions"""
      feature_class_parameter = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Input_Table", #0
                                      name="fc_settlements",
                                      datatype="DEFeatureClass",
                                      parameterType="Required",
                                      direction="Input")

      fieldMapParameter = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Primary Settlement Fields", #1
                              name="primary_fieldmap",
                              datatype="GPFieldMapping",
                              parameterType="Optional",
                              enabled=True,
                              direction="Input" )
      fieldMapParameter.parameterDependencies = [feature_class_parameter.name] # Doesn't seem to work
      params = [feature_class_parameter,fieldMapParameter]
      return params

  def updateParameters(self, parameters):
      if parameters[0].altered:
         parameters[1].addTable(parameters[0].valueAsText) # Fails with method not found
      return
  ```

[Full Toolbox](https://gist.github.com/kes1/8a22e6e092f2d0b55d64)

How do I associate these two parameters so they work like field mapping for the native tools such as Merge/Append etc ?

Comment: Changing the updateParameters to : 
`def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        if parameters[0].altered:
            tfms = arcpy.FieldMappings()
            tfms.addTable(parameters[0].valueAsText)
            parameters[1].value = tfms.exportToString()`  Seems to work, but it's pretty slow. There must be a more 'natural' way to set this ? I basically have a set of output fields that I'd like to be available to map *from* the input feature class.

Comment: I am working on the same exact functionality. Did you ever get this working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you wish to write your comment up as an answer, just flag this question to be re-opened so that you can do so.